# Border around ListView when IsEnabled is false

Tags: wpf, xaml, isenabled, systemcolors

When setting `IsEnabled` to `False` on a `ListView` I get a one pixel thick border around the control, with color `#F0F0F0` (on Win7).

I'm suspecting that it's one of the `SystemColors` kicking in. How do I set this borders `BorderThickness` to `0`, or failing that, which of the `SystemColors` do I override in my style to change it to the same as the control background?

I'm sure there are redundant rows in here, because I've been adding and removing things trying to solve the problem

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Types}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedType}" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=TypeCategoryIsSelected}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource LVItemStyle}" BorderThickness="0" Background="{StaticResource aBackground}" SelectionMode="Single">


</ListView>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="aBackground" Color="#FFFFE7" />

<DataTemplate x:Key="tDefaultTemplate">
    <Border BorderBrush="#CDCDCD" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FFFFFF" Width="325" Margin="15,2,15,2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <DockPanel Margin="1,1,1,1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
            <DockPanel.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#F2EFEF" Offset="0.0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#F6F5F5" Offset="0.5" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#F8F8F8" Offset="1.0" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </DockPanel.Background>
            <TextBlock Margin="20,0,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </DockPanel>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="tSelectedTemplate">
    <Border BorderBrush="#DDA4AB" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FFFFFF" Width="325" Margin="15,2,15,2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <DockPanel Margin="1,1,1,1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
            <DockPanel.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE0E3" Offset="0.0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE8EA" Offset="0.5" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#F6EAEB" Offset="1.0" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </DockPanel.Background>
            <TextBlock Margin="20,0,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </DockPanel>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" x:Key="LVItemStyle">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource tDefaultTemplate}" />
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#FFFFE7"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="#FFFFE7" />
    </Style.Resources>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource tSelectedTemplate}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource aBackground}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}" x:Key="LVStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource aBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#FFFFE7"/>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFFFE7"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource aBackground}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the code or XAML you use to create the `ListView`?

Comment: I would, but I can't get it to display withing the <code>-tags. :/

But it's really a no frills ListView, so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Post the code, then highlight and click the `{ }` symbol at the top of the post area to force into a code block. In failing that, post as text and I will see if I can force it into formatting. It's helpful to see the code so answerers know what to build on.

Comment: There we go! SO didn't like declarations spread over several rows. It looks a bit nasty, but you can copy it into an editor for better view.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've done some investigation and managed to find the cause of the problem (and a runtime resolution). I've ran out of time though so I will reveal my findings in the hopes you can finish off the investigation.

Firstly, I used a tool called [Snoop](https://github.com/cplotts/snoopwpf), which allows you to dig down into the rendered WPF and see values of all controls and display each layer. Using this, I managed to find that your `ListView` control contains a `Border` control. That `Border` has a `Padding` value of `1`, which is where your border is coming from (see below). Using Snoop's feature of changing runtime property values, I set this to `0` and sure enough, the border was gone.

[image: Cause of issue as seen through Snoop]

Chances are, you can control this in your `Style` somewhere. Either that, or perhaps one of the styles you are already using is causing it. I would try it out on a `ListView` without anything set (other than some basic items, size and disabled). This may help you find out if it's something you've caused or something internal within the `ListView` control.

If you are unable to find a way to fix this issue directly, you could try templating your `ListView` control by creating your own [`ControlTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate.aspx), which should then give you complete control over how it is rendered (though this may turn out to be a fair bit of work).

Comment: Wow! Excellent find. I don't change the padding anywhere, so it feels like some default behaviour of the control. I'm off work now, but I'll continue the investigation in the morrow.

Comment: @MarcusL It may well be. I would definitely recommend downloading Snoop and taking a look (it comes in handy an awful lot).

Comment: Yes, I've installed it, and I'm sure it'll be quite handy.